# Why can't I use 'this.' in C# to access my class constant?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

In C# .NET, why can't I access constants in a class with the 'this' keyword?

Example:

```
public class MyTest
{
    public const string HI = "Hello";

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        string filler;
        filler = this.HI; //Won't work.
        filler = HI       //Works.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because **class** constants aren't instance members; they're **class** members. The `this` keyword refers to an object, not the class, so you can't use it to refer to class constants.

This applies whether you're accessing the constant within a static or instance method in your class.

Comment: Somebody is speedy this morning. Haha.

Comment: @Justin Niessner: Have you been stalking me?!

Comment: No...but I was typing an answer myself when I saw that something was already posted.

Answer (score 4):

Constants are implicitly `static`.

Answer (score 3):

Because constants are part of the class, you need to use the class name:

```
filler = MyTest.HI;
```

Comment: In the class you don't need to do this.

Comment: True, you don't. I assumed he wanted to make it explicit where the constant was coming from.

Comment: @DanielRose Also, the syntax can be useful if the `const` field `HI` is _hidden_ by a method/constructor parameter or by a local variable which is also called `HI`. I.e. the same situation where `this.Hi2` is useful for non-static members `Hi2`.

Answer (score 2):

A const item is implicitly static. That means it belongs to the class and not the members of the class.